# Script to shutdown Linux Hostwhen Virtualbox Guest Windows is shutdown?

Tags: linux, virtualbox

I'm wondering if it's possible to auto shutdown a Linux Host when a Windows guest in Virtualbox is shutdown. I'm guessing some sort of script could do this?

Host: Linux Mint
Guest: Windows 7 and Windows 10.

When the user presses shutdown in Windows it would be good if Linux could also shutdown automatically shortly after the guest has safely shutdown.

Answer (score 0):

You can use scrpit in cron, that runs every 5 minutes or so. Something like that:

```
#!/bin/bash
VM_NAME='your_vm'
vboxmanage showvminfo $VM_NAME | grep -qE 'State: +powered off' && shutdown -h
```

Note, that it will shutdown any time, when VM is not running.

Comment: This looks like a good solution, just have two questions if that's ok, sorry if any seem a little noob.

1.) Is it possible to make the script check for multiple VM's E.g one Windows 7 another Windows 10. If neither are running shutdown If one is running don't shutdown.
2.) Is a cron job every 5 minutes by default or is it pretty straight forward for me to set my own time on when this should run?

Sorry for any noob questions, it's my first time needing to create a script like this and making a cron.

Comment: @Deltatash
1. It is possible, but you need to explain, what do you mean saying 'shutdown'. Is paused VM should be considered running? Is saved VM should be considered shutdown?
2. Cron have quite simple  syntax and can be set on different time. On most distros you can enter `crontab -e` and read the comments.

Answer (score 0):

There's a crude hackish way to do this. Here goes:

Anytime a guest image is shutdown, VirtualBox writes the current config back as a .vbox file (located under $HOME/.vbox)

1. Write a simple shell script which would check if the date modified matches with the current time and initiate a shutdown process of your Linux box.
2. Create a cron job that would run this script every 45 seconds for instance.

PS: You can make your script more intelligent by checking a buffer range of time - say modified within the last 5 minutes. By doing this, you can increase the cron job frequency to run every 4.45 minutes for efficiency.

PS2: This will trigger your host machine shutdown if you modify VirtualBox config when VM is running or just edit the config, since you modified the config.

Answer (score 0):

/usr/lib/virtualbox/VirtualBox --startvm "your_VM_name" && shutdown -P now

This will start your VM, and as soon as it is closed/shutdown will turn off the host. Tested on Kubuntu 18.04.